# Problem trying to convert a characterfile in R -- I can't seem to get as.numeric() to work right

Tags: r, character, numeric

Here is the question set up:

I have read in a data file from the Machine Learing Depository called "abalone.data":

```
dat=read.csv(file="abalone.data",header=FALSE)
colnames(dat)<-c('Sex','Length','Diameter','Height','Whole weight',
             'Shucked wieght','Viscera weight','Shell weight','Rings')
```

Here is a sample:

```
head(dat)
  Sex Length Diameter Height Whole weight Shucked wieght Viscera weight Shell weight Rings
1   M  0.455    0.365  0.095       0.5140         0.2245         0.1010        0.150    15
2   M  0.350    0.265  0.090       0.2255         0.0995         0.0485        0.070     7
3   F  0.530    0.420  0.135       0.6770         0.2565         0.1415        0.210     9
```

And here is the structure":

```
 str(dat)
 'data.frame':  4177 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Sex           : chr  "M" "M" "F" "M" ...
 $ Length        : num  0.455 0.35 0.53 0.44 0.33 0.425 0.53 0.545 0.475 0.55 ...
 $ Diameter      : num  0.365 0.265 0.42 0.365 0.255 0.3 0.415 0.425 0.37 0.44 ...
 $ Height        : num  0.095 0.09 0.135 0.125 0.08 0.095 0.15 0.125 0.125 0.15 ...
 $ Whole weight  : num  0.514 0.226 0.677 0.516 0.205 ...
 $ Shucked wieght: num  0.2245 0.0995 0.2565 0.2155 0.0895 ...
 $ Viscera weight: num  0.101 0.0485 0.1415 0.114 0.0395 ...

 $ Shell weight  : num  0.15 0.07 0.21 0.155 0.055 0.12 0.33 0.26 0.165 0.32 ...
 $ Rings         : int  15 7 9 10 7 8 20 16 9 19 ...
```

Here is the problem:

I want to convert the first row to numeric; e.g. "M" to 1, "F" to 2 and "I"to 3.

So, I try
Sex <- as.numeric(dat$Sex)

but I get:

```
Sex<-as.numeric(dat$sex)
> Sex[1:5]
```

[1] NA NA NA NA NA

I've tried a lot of similar commands; e.g.:

```
as.numeric(dat$Sex=character(),levels=levels)
Error: unexpected '=' in " as.numeric(dat$Sex="
```

I cannot figure this out.

Please help

Comment: Your question shows a lack of understanding of the basic principles of the language, I strongly recommend reading the documentation of a function using `help('as.numeric')` or biefly `?as.numeric` as well as the [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Sex variable is a character vector. You first need to change it to a factor:

```
dat$Sex <- as.numeric(factor(dat$Sex))
```